# Contents of Grub Menu On Booting

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 7 in a different partition. Then I formatted the partition where Windows 7 was installed.Now i want my grub menu to display only Ubuntu for Booting. But it is also showing Windows 7. Is there any way I can clean Grub Menu to Display Ubuntu Only not windows ??

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It will not find the Windows partition and will remove its entry from the Grub menu.